# Is Counter-Strike/Counter-Strike: Condition Zero compatible with CS: Source?

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-source

I bought the CounterStrike and CounterStrike: Condition Zero bundle on Steam yesterday. I proposed a friend of mine to download it as well, but she refused, as she already had bought CounterStrike: Source. Now, is it possible for us to play online (non-LAN, we live quite distant from each other), without having to buy the other's game?

If we do have to, which one of the three games would you suggest for two... "Non experienced" players?

One last question, as I've never dealt with online games on Steam before: assuming we can connect to each other, what would I have to do in order to set up a private game? Do I need a server?

Is it possible to host one on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inter-game play available between any of the titles, they are separate games with different systems, mechanics, weapons, maps, etc.

Having said that, all of the CS games are so very similar that there is little to choose between then regarding your question of suitability for "non experienced" players. You will find that they all play very similarly, and they all have similar learning curves. Given that I would recommend you play the most recent game. Of the 3 you listed that would be Counter Strike Source, although Counter Strike Global Offensive is even more recent. My reasoning is that the more recent games have larger player bases, better support for newer PC's going forwards, and better integration with Steam services.

You can create a passworded game and invite your friend to join you, your PC will act as the server. It's not ideal since the whole point of Counter Strike is going up against teams of humans, but it will work.

Counter Strike Source also support cross platform play between PC and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

None of the four Counter-Strike games (CS, CS:CZ, CS:S, CS:GO) are compatible with each other, either you or your friend will have to buy the other's game.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My skills are so bad, I'm seriously reconsidering the idea of buying another CS game. Minecraft it'll be, then...

Answer (score 1):

These games are separate. You will both need to have the relevant copies in order to play online together.

In relation to your other question - this is irrelevant as you are currently unable to connect to each other via different games.